# File Upload with unicode character symbol

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, iso-8859-1

All,
I'm  trying to upload a csv file and insert the contents of the file to a database table.
Everything seems to work fine, except when I have unicode character representing the TradeMark Symbol. i.e,
        **ABC ™**
When I try to insert this into the database, I get error mentioning its an incorrect character set.  The application is deployed on tomcat and the default encoding is **UTF8**

I tried all the following options, but nothing seems to work out.
1. Converted the input stream that holds the uploaded file object in to **UTF-8** .
2. Converted the input stream that holds the uploaded file object in to **iso-8859-1** .
3. Also tried using the getBytes() with different character encoding types.

And after the conversion in the java layer, I don't see the trademark sign but only **Â** . Could you please throw some light on this?

Comment: You have to set the schema encoding to UTF8 too

Comment: Any idea how do I set that?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: Sybasse, and the datatype of the specific column is varchar. I wont be able to do anything on DB end, all I can do is only from Java side.

Comment: Why? Without DB-end access you can't edit the schema encoding. However, [Here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01772.1600/doc/html/saiq-changing-collation-natlang.html) you can find the relevant sybase documentation

Comment: its already in production env, and changing that will involve a lot of pain.. tats y iwant to keep it simple via Java end.. One other thing is, when i sysout the uploaded file string, i still dont see the TM symbol even in java layer...(atleast if it inserts the record as \uxxxx into db, i can somehow convert/escape using commons stringutils)

Comment: Then you can convert it into a unicode literals and decode later it with java. You could also do the same thing with with HTML entities. The only way is to encode somehow the special characters and decode them after you select from the DB.

Comment: Ok i will try that.. But do you know why even after setting everything as UTF-8 format, I still dont see the TM symbol but only a Â character in java layer where I read the file stream before inserting into DB.

Comment: Likely because your console isn't set up for UTF8 characters. How are you executing your program? Which console do you use?

Comment: its a web-application deployed on tomcat, where in I upload a file using html page and use fileupload servlet process the stream. then I sysout the fields before inserting into db.. i see the sysout in the tomcat logs

Comment: Is the upload stream UTF8? Is the file saved as UTF8?

Comment: Am converting the stream as UTF-8, even before reading the file contents. InputStreamReader isr2 = new InputStreamReader(stream,cs1); where cs1 is utf-8. and the file is a default windows csv file

Comment: Check the file encoding. An easy way is: open Notepad++, click on the "Encoding" button on the menu bar and make sure that UTF-8 is selected

Comment: yep already tried that.. Tried with both UTF-8 and ANSI formats

Comment: What about the log file? Is it UTF8? If it is UTF8, I have no more clues.

Comment: I just did, OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
System.out.println("System Encoding --- " + out.getEncoding());  The format is UTF-8

Comment: Ok, but I asked for the encoding of the log file. If the system encoding is UTF8 but the log file is being written as ANSI, you'll get ANSI output on the file.

Comment: how to i find out that?